# Как заменить в тексте нужные слова другими в определённом участке?

Tags: java, if

Предположим, есть текст:

```
String s = "Pater noster, qui es in caelis; sanctificetur nomen tuum; 
adveniat regnum tuum; fiat { voluntas tua, sicut in caelo et in terra.
Panem nostrum quotidianum da nobis hodie; 
et dimitte nobis debita nostra,  
sicut et nos dimittimus debitoribus nostris } ; 
et ne nos inducas { in tentationem; sed libera nos } a malo. Amen"
```

Нужно "зайти" в него после символа **{**, заменить все **in** на **el**, если они есть и "выйти" если встретится символ **}** и продолжить далее по тексту с тем же условием.

Comment: С чем у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: Попробуйте разбить на массив строк - своего рода фразы. Каждый раз встречая fiat вы заходите и заменяете, при встрече фразы nostra - останавливаете.
Например, когда транслятор Морзе писал - использовал такой подход. Логически удобно и писать понятнее, чем в индексах и чарах копошиться.

Comment: @Asgard ваш подход меня заинтересовал, а можно поподробнее? Что значит, разбить на массив строк?